# how to manually throw a syntax error in javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

How can I manually throw a syntax error in a javascript function?

When a certain function in my program returns undefined, I want to throw a syntax error

Comment: eval "this wont compile will it!!!"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: If you get ans please accept, if you don't please comment.

Answer (score 3):

It's not recommended (because you should create your own exception to handle some unusual situations in your code), but if you must you can do it like this:

```
throw SyntaxError("your message")
```